# Debian KVM Host, Debian guests : where full-disk encryption should be done?

Tags: debian, kvm-virtualization, lvm, encryption

I have a host under Debian Wheezy, running qemu/KVM.

I want to have all my guests fully-encrypted.

I can see to possibilities :
- Either I encrypt the LVM Volume using dm-crypt (cryptsetup) and use the mapped device as the disk for the VM
- Or I encrypt the drive using debian-installer.

I can see one problem using the second solution : growing a volume is made pretty hard (shut down machine, resize LVM Volume from the host, chroot into the guest using live-cd, resize cryptsetup, resize lvm volume inside guest, resize filesystem, and then that bug that makes the machine take 4 hours to boot, and then it's done).

I would like some advices please !

Thank you!